# How to Typeset This RC and RL Circuits

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, qcircuit

Please, I need the latex code that will typeset the following circuits. I will be grateful if help in this regard is rendered.

Please I don't even know how to start. Help me.

[image: RC and RL Circuits]

Comment: This site is for conceptual problems that potential also can help others. It is not for posting a picture and expect others to do your work. You need to try and then describe where you are stuck. (Post compilable code if possible)

Comment: as per profile none of the previous answers to questions posted by the OP have been accepted

Comment: I do upvote answers. Answers to the previous questions were well useful and acknowledged. Please help me